# Error Creating New Windows Local User in Chef

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, local, windows-server-2012

The following PowerShell code to create two dummy accounts works fine for me when ran in the ISE:

```
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString –AsPlainText –Force R4ndomT3xt

New-LocalUser -Name User1 -password $Password -PasswordNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword

New-LocalUser -Name User2 -password $Password -PasswordNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword

net user User1 /active:no

net user User2 /active:no
```

But when used in the following Chef recipe:

```
powershell_script 'Dummy' do

  code <<-EOH

                $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString –AsPlainText –Force R4ndomT3xt

                    New-LocalUser -Name User1 -password $Password -PasswordNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword

                    New-LocalUser -Name User2 -password $Password -PasswordNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword

                    net user User1 /active:no

                    net user User2 /active:no

      EOH

    End
```

..throws

"...Cannot bind parameter 'SecureKey'. Cannot convert the "R4ndomT3xt" value

of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".

- CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: ( [Write-Error], WriteErrorExcep

tion

- FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptio

n,chef-script20170918-4004-f15k8h..." etc

Can anyone suggest why the string conversion to SecureString works in the ISE but fails in the Chef recipe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString –AsPlainText –Force R4ndomT3xt
```

With

```
$Password = "R4ndomT3xt" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText –Force
```

Happy for someone to expand on *why* this works.